# Modifying CSV Row data

Tags: powershell

Every month I manually run some PS commands and manually modify the exported CSV.

I have automated this, but cannot figure out how to modify the "Licenses" column.

Each row should show specific test, in this case "LICENSE=TYPE1"

Type1 is an internal use name, so I can't pull this from anywhere.

When I generate the file "System.Collections" is placed in the "Licenses" column.  I need to replace the text.

If my CSV file contains the column header "LICENSE", how can I modify every cell in that column to contain the text "LICENSE=TYPE1"?

I've tried this:

```
Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.Licenses).AccountSkuId -contains "ENTRPRISEPACK"} 
| Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Office, City, State, Licenses | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\LICENSES.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\LICENSE.CSV" | ForEach-Object {
If ($_.Licenses -like  "System.Collections") {
    $_.Licenses = "LICENSE=TYPE1"
}
$_
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\LICENSE123.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

What am I missing?!

This is how the CSV file is created:

```
Get-MsolUser |
  Where {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true } |
  Select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Office, City, State, @{n="Licenses";e={$_.Licenses.AccountSKUid}} | 
  Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\LICENSES.CSV" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: 'When I generate the file "System.Collections" is placed in the "Licenses" column' - how do you generate it in the first place?

Comment: Since you want to modify every row for that column in CSV file why don't you just explicitly specify columns and instead of License column set the value you need.

Comment: `$_.Licenses` is not a string but an object of type `System.Collections`. Try: `If($_.Licenses -is  [System.Collections]) {...`.

Comment: Unable to find type [System.Collections].
At line:2 char:24
+     If($_.Licenses -is [System.Collections]) {
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collections:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Sorry, I just want to make sure I'm clear.  The text written in the CSV file actually says "[System.Collections]".

Comment: @KirillPashkov I'm not sure how I would do that.

If I export the config from O365, how can I do what you're saying?

Comment: I ended up modifying the Get-MSOLUser command to:
See original question

Comment: `System.Collections` is a namespace. You're only seeing part of the type name. If you find the full type name, you can use the `-is` operator as suggested earlier.